# Rails/Heroku Application Error - ActionView::Templete::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionview

When I deploy my app to Heroku I am getting an error page saying "We're sorry, but something went wrong." I add puma to my gem file in order to run the server there. Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue. I'm working in Cloud 9 IDE. The logs are posted below. Can anyone assist?

```
>     freshmurry:~/workspace (master) $ heroku logs --tail
>     WARNING: This is the legacy Heroku CLI with limited functionality. Please install the latest CLI.
>     WARNING: Installation instructions are at https://cli.heroku.com
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118206+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118197+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:7296
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118218+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118219+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Private Caller
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118220+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 1
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118223+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118221+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118246+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118403+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:7296
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.127987+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 7) booted, phase: 0
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.118634+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.138176+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 12) booted, phase: 0
>     2017-06-12T14:42:28.468279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
>     2017-06-12T14:43:21.618239+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 165.225.0.80 at 2017-06-12 14:43:21 +0000
>     2017-06-12T14:43:21.661531+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
>     2017-06-12T14:43:21.676339+00:00 app[web.1]:   Product Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
>     2017-06-12T14:43:51.612669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/"
> host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=a209d2c5-1519-4829-b03f-8ad410a36cc7 fwd="165.225.0.80"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T14:43:51.738309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=716c5e18-d421-49fd-9c3f-a1b406ef950d fwd="165.225.0.80"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=188
> protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.815485+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (58144.2ms)
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.815964+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 58154ms (ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819108+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819110+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...   background: ":
> expected "{", was "url('/assets/si..."):
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819112+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <div class="product clearfix">
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819113+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:    <a href="<%= product_path(product)%>">
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819113+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <div class="product-image-container">
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819114+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:      <img src="<%= asset_path product.thumbnail_image_name %>" alt="<%=
> product.title %>"/>
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819115+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:      <span class="product-price">$<%= product.price %></span>
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819116+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:    </div>
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819117+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:    <p class="product-title"><%= product.title %></p></a>
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819118+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:16:in `block in
> _app_views_products_index_html_erb__2962215687888486859_70188315801060'
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819118+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:12:in
> `_app_views_products_index_html_erb__2962215687888486859_70188315801060'
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T14:44:19.819119+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T14:50:12.196944+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 165.225.0.83 at 2017-06-12 14:50:12 +0000
>     2017-06-12T14:50:12.246560+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
>     2017-06-12T14:50:12.260255+00:00 app[web.1]:   Product Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.705756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=cb4de3d8-9abf-4c68-b7b3-08247b55c803 fwd="165.225.0.83"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6512ms status=500 bytes=1714
> protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.758818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=aa8706d9-9053-40ee-b586-c95a2324af8d fwd="165.225.0.83"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=93 protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706025+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:    <a href="<%= product_path(product)%>">
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.704334+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6458ms (ActiveRecord: 9.5ms)
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706028+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:    </div>
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706020+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.704044+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6448.0ms)
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706026+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <div class="product-image-container">
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706026+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:      <img src="<%= asset_path product.thumbnail_image_name %>" alt="<%=
> product.title %>"/>
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706024+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <div class="product clearfix">
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706027+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:      <span class="product-price">$<%= product.price %></span>
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706023+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...   background: ":
> expected "{", was "url('/assets/si..."):
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706029+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:    <p class="product-title"><%= product.title %></p></a>
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706030+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:16:in `block in
> _app_views_products_index_html_erb__2962215687888486859_70188315745620'
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706031+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:12:in
> `_app_views_products_index_html_erb__2962215687888486859_70188315745620'
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706031+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T14:50:18.706032+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T15:00:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user user@yahoo.com
>     2017-06-12T15:00:26.386944+00:00 app[api]: Release v35 created by user user@yahoo.com
>     2017-06-12T15:00:26.386944+00:00 app[api]: Deploy bfdfd983 by user user@yahoo.com
>     2017-06-12T15:00:27.042332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
>     2017-06-12T15:00:27.043183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
>     2017-06-12T15:00:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>     2017-06-12T15:00:28.141928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>     2017-06-12T15:00:28.160932+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
>     2017-06-12T15:00:28.933799+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] === puma shutdown: 2017-06-12 15:00:28 +0000 ===
>     2017-06-12T15:00:28.933814+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Goodbye!
>     2017-06-12T15:00:28.933834+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
>     2017-06-12T15:00:29.287412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
>     2017-06-12T15:00:33.688417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10601 -e production`
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161643+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161681+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:10601
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161691+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161692+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161754+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161823+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Private Caller
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161864+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 1
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161937+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Environment: production
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.161980+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Process workers: 2
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.162025+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Preloading application
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.162303+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:10601
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.162802+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.175712+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 7) booted, phase: 0
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.178719+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 9) booted, phase: 0
>     2017-06-12T15:00:42.741234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
>     2017-06-12T15:03:34.480518+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 165.225.0.80 at 2017-06-12 15:03:34 +0000
>     2017-06-12T15:03:34.535895+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
>     2017-06-12T15:03:34.556604+00:00 app[web.1]:   Product Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
>     2017-06-12T15:04:04.458759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/"
> host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=99da6242-45eb-4039-b35c-770b1594beec fwd="165.225.0.80"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T15:04:34.582637+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=songchordz.herokuapp.com
> request_id=734596fb-2cb9-4bd4-9cc5-4fc85c747ed5 fwd="165.225.0.80"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.462061+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (74910.8ms)
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.467310+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74931ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470398+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470410+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...   background: ":
> expected "{", was "url('/assets/si..."):
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470412+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     <div class="product clearfix">
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470414+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:    <a href="<%= product_path(product)%>">
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470415+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <div class="product-image-container">
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470415+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:      <img src="<%= asset_path product.thumbnail_image_name %>" alt="<%=
> product.title %>"/>
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470416+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:      <span class="product-price">$<%= product.price %></span>
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470418+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:    </div>
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470419+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:    <p class="product-title"><%= product.title %></p></a>
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470420+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:16:in `block in
> _app_views_products_index_html_erb__4490733878524225278_70102825789420'
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470421+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/products/index.html.erb:12:in
> `_app_views_products_index_html_erb__4490733878524225278_70102825789420'
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>     2017-06-12T15:04:49.470422+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: well I do see this error: `2017-06-12T15:04:49.470410+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "...   background: ":
> expected "{", was "url('/assets/si..."):`

Comment: Try running `heroku run rake assets:precompile` to see if that shows you errors in your assets.

Comment: That helped as well... the root of the issue was in my application.css.scss file. I had to remove the "css" extension.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see an error like this:

```
2017-06-12T15:04:49.470410+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "... background: ": > expected "{", was "url('/assets/si..."):
```

it serves as a clue. The clue is in the term ActionView::Template. Its important to know how the Ruby on Rails framework works for you to understand what is going on. Here is a guide on what is the significance of ActionView:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

Rails uses this tool called ActionView and what ActionView does is assist in mapping the controllers to the Views, but don't take my word for it, just read the documentation I posted above, in particular this part:

For each controller there is an associated directory in the app/views directory which holds the template files that make up the views associated with that controller. These files are used to display the view that results from each controller action.

So why am I posting this? Well, if you know that ActionView maps the controllers to the views and then you also see the term Template, it serves as a big clue that the problem is in the Views of your Model-Views-Controller application. Isn't awesome how you can isolate the problem with this framework in this manner?

Then there is another clue in that error message, Invalid CSS after...

I think that is the biggest and glaring clue of all. You have invalid CSS and its not rendering in your Views correctly, which is why the terms Template and ActionView appeared on the error scene.

I realize you figured it out eventually, but the answer is also in how you problem solve and not just the fix. Eventually, you are going to run into another error that you can't decipher if you do not know how the Ruby on Rails MVC framework and all of its tools work.